# error while running update-initramfs

Tags: initramfs

i get this error by running: "sudo update-initramfs -u"

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-37-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda2
I: (UUID=9cf453b8-6c3d-45b6-9485-6473494bb6ad)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing firmware is in package linux-firmware.

You can get it with

```
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

for the second part, I know only how it works with an swap partition, not with a swapfile

```
lsblk -f | grep swap
```

so you can found if you have a swap partition.

```
sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

then add the uuid there in this manner.

```
RESUME=UUID=your uuid
```

besides, it is only a given Info not an error.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

Will update the initrd from your current running kernel.